# Dictionary with multiple strings from config file as values

Tags: python, regex, bash

I have following config file:

```
object-group network NAME1
 network-object host ipaddr1/mask
object-group network NAME2
 network-object host ipaddr2/mask
 network-object host ipaddr3/mask
object-group network NAME3
 network-object ipaddr4/mask
 network-object ipaddr5/mask
 network-object ipaddr6/mask
 network-object ipaddr7/mask
 network-object ipaddr8/mask
object-group network NAME3
 network-object ipaddr9/mask
[...]
```

Which I need to parse in following manner:
Dictionary() where:

- key is object group name
- value is list of ip addresses in that object group

What is the easiest way to do so in python or bash? Using dictionary is not obligatory - I just need to be able to easily replace group name with all ip addresses assigned to that group in my config files.

Comment: please review [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then come back and update your question; in particular, show what code you've tried, the (wrong) output you're generating, and the desired output (for the given sample input)

Answer (score 1):

```
{network:re.findall('[./0-9]+', ips) for network, ips in re.findall(r'object-group network ([\S]+?)((?:[\n ]+network-object .*)+)', your_string)}
```

shoud be your desired dictionary, returns (e.g.)

`{'NAME1': ['192.168.0.1/1'], 'NAME2': ['192.168.0.2/1', '192.168.0.2/2']}`

**Explanation:**

`(?:[\n ]+network-object .*)+` matches as many network-objects as we can. `?:` is a not capturing match as the group would be continuously overwritten (using  `(a)+` on `aaaaaa` will return only one group containing `a`!)

The findall returns a list of tuples `[(a, b), (c,d)]` so we can now use `x,y in list_of_tuple` to unpack them. In the first iteration we will get `x=a` and `y=b` and in the second `x=c` and `y=d`. Now we only have to find the ips in our second tuple which is why we use the regex `'[./0-9]+'`.
Also using dict comprehension:

`{key: value for key,value in [(key1, value1),(key2,value2)]}`